# SubQuery SQL with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have this query who count the number of articles created on a period X by RAY.

```sql
select count(DISTINCT REF_ART_NOART) as NB_ART,[RAY]  
from #tempValidate 
left join ARTICLE_BASE on article_code = REF_ART_NOART 
where REF_DTSAISIE between '20201001' and '20201021' and [SUB_RAY] = 1 
group by [RAY] order by [RAY]
```

This show me this result :

```
NB_ART | RAY 
892    | 3
61     | 8
807    | 10
```

Now I have this query who count the number of article created on a period X and which have a DCF_DTCOMMAN as null by RAY again

```sql
select count(DISTINCT REF_ART_NOART) as NB_ART_NOT_USE from #tempValidate
left join #tempInfo on DCF_NOART= REF_ART_NOART  
left join ARTICLE_BASE on article_code = REF_ART_NOART
where DCF_DTCOMMAN is null and REF_DTSAISIE between '20201001' and '20201021'  and [SUB_RAY] = 1
group by [RAY] order by [RAY]`
```

This show me this result :

```
NB_ART | RAY 
705    | 3
40     | 8 
600    | 10
```

My question is how can I manage both query into one query to get this result ?

```
NB_ART |NB_ART_NOT_USE| RAY 
892    | 705          | 3
61     | 40           | 8             
807    | 600          | 10
```

I think it's possible to do this by a subquery but I don't get it here. If someone can give me an example or some advice to do this.

Comment: If you have more to add to your question, [edit] it.

Comment: It would help greatly if you include table structures (including table structures of the temporary tables) or, at a minimum, include which tables each field comes from. Also, do both temp tables have the same `ray` values in them (e.g., if it exists in one, it exists in the other)?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to post the table structures too. Next time I wouldn't forget to do it. 
The solution below work fine, thank you for you for the time spent for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to a subquery, just use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT TV.REF_ART_NOART) as NB_ART,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TV.DCF_DTCOMMAN IS NULL THEN TV.REF_ART_NOART END) AS NB_ART_NOT_USE,
       TV.RAY
FROM #tempValidate TV
    --LEFT JOIN #tempInfo TI ON TV.DCF_NOART = TI.REF_ART_NOART
    --LEFT JOIN ARTICLE_BASE AB ON TV.article_code = AB.REF_ART_NOART
WHERE TV.REF_DTSAISIE BETWEEN '20201001' AND '20201021' 
  AND TV.[SUB_RAY] = 1
GROUP BY TV.[RAY]
ORDER BY TV.[RAY];
```

I've also commented out both `JOIN`s here, as it appears neither are actually needed. As I can only assume that `REF_DTSAISIE` and `SUB_RAY` are in the table `#tempValidate`, due to them being in the `WHERE` and `NULL`ability not be handled then the other tables don't appear to be being used.

Of course, if I am wrong, then your `LEFT JOIN`s are actually implicit `INNER JOIN`s; but that's impossible to know due to a lack of the columns being qualified.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, she works fine. However, it's necesary to keep both join, I need some data in these table. For example, SUB_RAY are in the table ARTICLE_BASE.  
I didn't know that the case when could solve my problem.

Comment: Then it would seem your `LEFT JOIN`s are implicit `INNER JOIN`s @KJ4Saeko . You need to either move the criteria to the`ON`, or make the `JOIN`s an `INNER JOIN`. I also, however, strongly recommend qualifying your columns, as we have no idea where those columns are otherwise.